# How did classic side scrollers implement timed events and animation triggers?

Tags: graphics, assembly

I have always been amazed at the Super Mario series on the Snes. I think it was mostly made in Z80 assembly. But since there was not a real time clock, how on earth did they manage all those timed, animated events with assembly and no real time clock?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "real time clock", but the consoles that relied on the Z80 as a general-purpose processor also had dedicated hardware for animating sprites and playing sounds. The Z80 was just feeding orders to these.

Comment: I would love to know this too! I just always thought it was more of a "when X is here, Y does this" kinda thing.

Comment: Old games are often synchronized around the frame rate of the screen they run on so they update their sprites once per frame (i.e 50hz or 60hz depending on if it's a PAL or an NTSC system)

Comment: Super Mario on the SNES: Super Mario World and Yoshi's Island. Neither of those are Z80. That was GB(C)

Comment: @Kawa - indeed, NES and SNES were based on customized MOS 65xx cores, the Ricoh 2A03 and 5A22 respectively. btw, what's GB(C)?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An important concept to keep in mind is the VSync rate. This is how often the electron gun in the TV (or, the equivalent in modern TVs) finish drawing the screen, and slowly travel up to the top of the screen.

Because this happens at a constant rate (60 times/second in NTSC, 50 in PAL), most games use this as their timer, with code that is roughly equivalent to this:

```
void main() {
    while(true) {
        updateGame();
        updateSprites();
        waitForVSync();
    }
}
```

Obviously, this is grossly simplified, but that's what's going on. Some games were so complex that they took too long and missed the VSync period. In that case, they'd wait for the second VSync, and thus run at 30 (/25) FPS.

Sometimes, you'll notice slow down in NES games (for example). This is when the work load is so heavy that it's missing several VSync periods in a single frame of action.

But yeah, that's the gist of how timing worked on older consoles (Actually, even many newer consoles and PC games use the same system, not just old consoles!)

Comment: what is this 'morally equivalent' that you keep saying? i do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: I was using it such that "X is morally equivalent to Y" means, roughly, "X is not the same as Y, and is probably quite different, but serves a similar purpose". Upon doing some research, I realize that I was using it incorrectly, so I will edit it out of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A very common technique used on  old hardware was to rely on the same timing hardware used for displaying graphics.  The old hardware literally streamed data out of its graphics port (composite video, or more commonly RF) by reading a pixel value from memory and putting it out on the port, along with some 'sync' signals, to control the scanning electron gun in the television.

The nice bit is that the vertical sync signal, the one that makes the gun swing from the bottom of the screen to the top, is usually connected to a hardware interrupt on the CPU of the console, and at that very moment, which happens exactly 29.97 times per second (almost 30fps) occurs at a moment when no data is being sent over the video at all, because it takes some time for the beam to 'fly back' to the top of the screen.  Changes made in video memory at that time will be flicker free!

Comment: On most older systems, there was no distinction made between even and odd fields, so the video frame rate was about 60Hz.  It's also interesting to note that on the Atari 2600, the processor was responsible for generating the vertical timing, and frame rates could thus be higher or lower than 60Hz, within the tolerance of a television set.  One of the chips (the "RIOT") included a down counter with a prescalar, which could be set before running a piece of code which would take an uncertain amount of time to execute, but there were no interrupts.

Answer (score 2):

Games, then as now, typically run a fixed time-step loop (see Mike Carons answer). Originally, this was mainly for convenience; your rendering was synchronized to the display refresh rate anyway to avoid tearing, might as well run all time-based processing once per frame.

Nowadays, most games still advance time in discrete steps which are a multiple of some base rate, usually 50/60 Hz or something like 100 Hz - some titles still have VSync-based timing, but most just use regular timers for this now. Nowadays we use fixed timesteps for slightly different reasons: First, games typically have at least some amount of physics simulation going on, and it is very hard to get physical simulation with variable timesteps stable - especially in real-time applications like games, where you can't easily throw more computing power at it by using more accurate integration methods and the like. Second, if you have *any* kind of networked multiplayer mode, you need to make sure that the game stays in sync for all players. This is nearly impossible to manage (and debug) if everyone is on a different timer and processes events at a different rate. Forcing everyone to use a common time-step makes the problem several orders of magnitude easier to manage, because you can safely assume that two players that start in identical state and get identical input will still be in an identical state 5 seconds later, even if the players look at different things or have different machines, all of which influences the actual frame rate that the game runs at (and hence also the rate at which the game can process events).

Answer (score 0):

The Z80 supports a number of hardware interrupts - it is possible one of these was connected to a periodic timer (eg. Every 10ms). Some early games consoles had timing related to the TV scan refresh, so this may have been hooked up. I don't know the SNES, so I'm speculating based on how other contemporary systems worked.

wikipedia says that the SNES was a 16 bit system, so it wasn't a Z80, which is 8 bit.
Actually it says it was a 65c816

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Nintendo_Entertainment_System

(the above link talks about video sync interrupts, so I'm probably on the right lines assuming you are correct about the real time clock)